# Copying a Google sheet into new sheets while maintaining the original Importrange data

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have 3 different master sheets:

(1) `Hours`
(2) `Hours` & `Wages`
(3) `Master labor`: $ sheet

Each sheet is connected. For example:
The hours are entered on sheet (1).
Sheet (2) has the wages, multiplies the hours from sheet (1) and gives a total amount spent in labor.
These numbers are then pulled to sheet (3) for a daily snapshot of labor dollars spent.

They are all connected using the `importrange` function.  It took quite some time to build these sheets and I would like to be able to save as (January, February, March etc.) while keeping the importranges.

When you use the copy function it assigns a new url and they don't talk to each other. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Provide sample sheet with input and sample of desired output.

Comment: @CodeCamper                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                            
Schedule Hours https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SJ7OzGMh7RipJiSLt23GUCPH_7tKTpPEWv_MP6MTDOM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CodeCamper  Wage $  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6VtwHQCbkVv8XrHZK57ieAh6v9bRcrxX1rVQT5DGmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CodeCamper Financial https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QB5jUcA_qeuv2U6ZM3FUgn1eFz2jEfPiH75O4ZgGsfc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet showing the output you want? It probably makes sense to put this all in one google sheet you can still use the importrange on different sheets to simulate the problem.

Comment: You should be aware that by choosing to share your spreadsheet, your email address will be unavoidably exposed.

Comment: Solution#1: Easy - don't use three spreadsheets; Solution#2: include all months in each spreadsheet by using a separate sheet for each month - then the `importrange` need only pickup the new month; Solution#3: Create an assumptions sheet on each spreadsheet that imports data from another. On the assumptions sheet, include fields for the url of the linked sheets, then edit the `importrange` formula to pull the url from the field on the assumptions sheet. Then when you copy a month, you just need to edit the url once; Solution#4:  write a script to do the copy, and have it `setformula` .